# Change input value based on

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In my Ruby on Rails application I have table with car prices. This table has the following inputs:

- Car from_days
- Car to_days
- Car netto_price
- Car brutto_price

I have the following html code(I convert it to HAML to be more readable)

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  %thead
    %tr
      %th
        Od [Liczba dni]
      %th
        Do [Liczba dni]
      %th
        Cena netto
      %th
        Cena brutto
      %th
  %tbody#prices
    %tr.nested-fields
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_from_days
          %input#car_prices_attributes_0_from_days.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{name: "car[prices_attributes][0][from_days]", step: "1", type: "number", value: "1"}/
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_to_days
          %input#car_prices_attributes_0_to_days.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{name: "car[prices_attributes][0][to_days]", step: "1", type: "number", value: "12"}/
      %td
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_netto_price
          %input#car_prices_attributes_0_netto_price.string.optional.form-control{min: "0", name: "car[prices_attributes][0][netto_price]", type: "text", value: "123,00"}/
      %td.brutto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_brutto_price
          %input#car_prices_attributes_0_brutto_price.string.optional.form-control{min: "0", name: "car[prices_attributes][0][brutto_price]", type: "text", value: "151,29"}/
      %td.remove
        %input#car_prices_attributes_0__destroy{name: "car[prices_attributes][0][_destroy]", type: "hidden", value: "213"}/
        %a.delete.remove_fields.existing{href: "#", style: "display: none;"}
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
    %input#car_prices_attributes_0_id{name: "car[prices_attributes][0][id]", type: "hidden", value: "213"}/
    %tr.nested-fields
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_from_days
          %input#car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_from_days.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][from_days]", step: "1", type: "number"}/
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_to_days
          %input#car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_to_days.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][to_days]", step: "1", type: "number"}/
      %td
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_netto_price
          %input#car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_netto_price.string.optional.form-control{min: "0", name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][netto_price]", type: "text", value: "0,00"}/
      %td.brutto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_brutto_price
          %input#car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_brutto_price.string.optional.form-control{min: "0", name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][brutto_price]", type: "text", value: "0,00"}/
      %td.remove
        %input#car_prices_attributes_1406871212209__destroy{name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][_destroy]", type: "hidden", value: "false"}/
        %a.delete.remove_fields.dynamic{href: "#"}
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
```

And now I want to build feature like this:

- When one of the netto_price inputs changed, set its closest brutto_price input to ((netto_price*0.23) + netto_price)
- when one of the brutto_price inputs changed, set its closest netto_price input to (brutto_price - (netto_price*0.23)

I will be very grateful for any help because I've stuck...

My code:

```
  $("input#car_prices_attributes_0_netto_price").change ->
    value = (@.value * 0.23)
    brutto = $("input#car_prices_attributes_0_netto_price").closest($('[id*="brutto_price"]'))
    brutto.val(value)
```

I've only tried to do this on on netto_price input to when netto_price_input change, update also brutto_price input. But I have problem with this closest method. It not work properly.

Edit:
Could anyone modificate my code to set brutto_price input value based on netto_price input value?

Comment: Also paste the code you have tried. If you have not tried writing code yet, you should research and try something first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer, you need to add classes to parent `td` of your `netto` and `brutto` fields, as shown in the code.

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Od [Liczba dni]
      %th Do [Liczba dni]
      %th Cena netto
      %th Cena brutto
      %th
  %tbody#prices
    %tr.nested-fields
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_from_days
          %input#car_prices_attributes_0_from_days.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{class: "/>{name:"}>/
          [prices_attributes][0][from_days] ", step: "1 ", type: "number ", value: "1 "}/
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_to_days
          %input.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_0_to_days "}>/
          {name: "car[prices_attributes][0][to_days] ", step: "1 ", type: "number ", value: "12 "}/
      %td.netto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_netto_price
          %input.string.optional.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_0_netto_price "}>/
          {min: "0 ", name: "car[prices_attributes][0][netto_price] ", type: "text ", value: "123,00 "}/
      %td.brutto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_brutto_price
          %input.string.optional.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_0_brutto_price "}>/
          {min: "0 ", name: "car[prices_attributes][0][brutto_price] ", type: "text ", value: "151,29 "}/
      %td.remove
        %input{id: "car_prices_attributes_0__destroy "}>/
        {name: "car[prices_attributes][0][_destroy] ", type: "hidden ", value: "213 "}/
        %a.delete.remove_fields.existing
          {href: "# ", style: "display: none; "}
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
    = succeed "{name:" do
      %input{id: "car_prices_attributes_0_id "}/
    %tr.nested-fields
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_from_days
          %input.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_from_days "}>/
          {name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][from_days] ", step: "1 ", type: "number "}/
      %td
        .form-group.integer.optional.car_prices_to_days
          %input.numeric.integer.optional.form-control.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_to_days "}>/
          {name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][to_days] ", step: "1 ", type: "number "}/
      %td.netto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_netto_price
          %input.string.optional.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_netto_price "}>/
          {min: "0 ", name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][netto_price] ", type: "text ", value: "0,00 "}/
      %td.brutto
        .form-group.string.optional.car_prices_brutto_price
          %input.string.optional.form-control{id: "car_prices_attributes_1406871212209_brutto_price "}>/
          {min: "0 ", name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][brutto_price] ", type: "text ", value: "0,00 "}/
      %td.remove
        %input{id: "car_prices_attributes_1406871212209__destroy "}>/
        {name: "car[prices_attributes][1406871212209][_destroy] ", type: "hidden ", value: "false "}/
        %a.delete.remove_fields.dynamic
          {href: "# "}
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
```

After that add coffee code like this:

```
$ ->
  $(".netto input").change ->
    netto_price = @value
    value = ((netto_price * 0.23) + netto_price)
    brutto = $(this).closest(".nested-fields").find(".brutto input")
    brutto.val value


  $(".brutto input").change ->
    brutto_price = @value
    value = (brutto_price - (brutto_price * 0.23))
    netto = $(this).closest(".nested-fields").find(".netto input")
    netto.val value
```

**Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kndWe/3/)**

Comment: nice.. :) There is a scope of improvement in `coffee` code. You can improve it in your way, if you want...